# Cross-Compiling for an embedded ARM-based Linux system

Tags: gcc, embedded, arm, cross-compiling

I try to compile some C code for an embedded (custom) ARM-based Linux system. I set up an Ubuntu VM with a cross-compiler named arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.4 because it looked like what I needed. Now when I compile my code with this gcc, it produces a binary like this:

```
$ file test1
test1: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked
(uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.31,
BuildID[sha1]=0x51b8d560584735be87adbfb60008d33b11fe5f07, not stripped
```

When I try to run this binary on the embedded Linux, I get

```
$ ./test1
-sh: ./test1: not found
```

Permissions are sufficient. I can only imagine that something's wrong with the binary format, so I looked at some working binary as reference:

```
$ file referenceBinary
referenceBinary: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1, dynamically linked
(uses shared libs), stripped
```

I see that there are some differences, but I do not have the knowledge to derive what exactly I need to fix and how I can fix that. Can someone explain which difference is critical?

Another thing I looked at are the dependencies:

```
$ ldd test1
    libc.so.6 => not found (0x00000000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.3 => /lib/ld-linux.so.3 (0x00000000)
```

(Interestingly, this works on the target system although it cannot execute the binary.) The embedded system only has a `libc.so.0` available. I guess I need to tell the compiler the libc version I want to link against, but as I understand it, gcc just links against the version it comes with, is this correct? What can I do about it?

Edit: Here's the Makefile I use:

```
CC=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.4
STRIP=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-strip          
CFLAGS=-I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include             
LDFLAGS=-nostdlib
LDLIBS=../libc.so.0

SRCS=test1.c
OBJS=$(subst .c,.o,$(SRCS))

all: test1

test1: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o main $(OBJS) $(LDLIBS)
    $(STRIP) main

depend: .depend

.depend: $(SRCS)
    rm -f ./.depend
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM $^>>./.depend;

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS)

include .depend
```

Comment: If you're tight on memory, the much smaller `uClibc` can substitute for `glibc`.  However you would need a *gcc* compiler built to use `uClibc`.  One (relatively) easy method of obtaining a working toolchain of *gcc*, *uClibc* (or *glibc*) and friends plus building the Linux kernel, Busybox and other packages all from source is to use `BuildRoot`.  With a good compiler + libc combination, you can link your app statically, and be independent of the target's libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you should probably do is to install `libc6` on the embedded system. Read [this thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-embedded-78/compile-code-for-arm-processor-703336/) about a similar problem. The solution in post #5 was to install:

```
libc6_2.3.6.ds1-13etch9_arm.deb
linux-kernel-headers_2.6.18-7_arm.deb
libc6-dev_2.3.6.ds1-13etch9_arm.deb
```

Your other option is to get the `libc` from the embedded system onto your VM and then pass it to the `gcc` linker and use the `-static` option.

This solution was also mentioned in the above thread. Read more about static linking [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html).

**Other things to try:**

In [this thread](https://forum.sparkfun.com/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=32040) they suggest removing the `-mabi=apcs-gnu` flag from your makefile if you're using one.

[This article](http://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/12/05/using-ubuntu-arm-cross-compiler-for-bare-metal-programming/) suggests feedint gcc the `-nostdlib` flag if you're compiling from the command line.

Or you could switch to using the `arm-none-eabi-gcc` compiler. References on this can be found [here](http://www.kunen.org/uC/gnu_tool.html) and [here](https://github.com/jsnyder/arm-eabi-toolchain).

Comment: I cannot install software on the embedded system, but linking to the system's libc brought up this error: `ld: error: Source object ../libc.so.0 has EABI version 0, but target main has EABI version 5`. The google results for this error imply that I actually need a different gcc, is this correct?

Comment: @flyx Are you using a makefile or are you running gcc directly on the command line?

Comment: arm-none-eabi-gcc is probably the right choice. I didn't try because I got a working toolchain from the hardware manufacturer, but I'll mark this as correct answer anyway. The links were quite helpful.